# Ebook Java Card 3?

Tags: javacard

i need to use Java card in my application for check user information and handle user information or handle some business logic example store user borrow book in his card. . .
but i new in java card, i know it now have version 3 (Java card version 3) who's have any book tutorials or ebook can share for me learn Java card 3

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

- Java Card Technology for Smart Cards:
  Architecture and Programmer's Guide
  by Zhiqun Chen
- Smart Card Application
  Development Using Java, by Uwe
  Hansmann, Frank Seliger,Martin S.
  Nicklous

Also a tutorial I found quite useful
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-07-1999/jw-07-javacard.html?page=1

A.E

Comment: Scan around javaworld they have some pretty comprehensive tutorials and guides e.g. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-1998/jw-03-javadev.html?